# VBA Code Not returning the expected results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some VBA that I am using in a module in access.  My Data looks like,

**SectionID**------**Left_Img** 
---------------------------------
---19--------------394
---26--------------781
---83--------------842
---83--------------450
---83--------------453
---83--------------456
--104--------------621
--104--------------622

I need to generate a sample number for these numbers. The data should look like this,

**SectionID**------**Left_Img**-----**Sample**-- 
--------------------------------------------------
---19--------------394-----------------1
---26--------------781-----------------1
---83--------------842-----------------1
---83--------------450-----------------2
---83--------------453-----------------3
---83--------------456-----------------4
--104--------------621-----------------1
--104--------------622-----------------2

I have written some vba but it is returning the following results,
**SectionID**------**Left_Img**-----**Sample**-- 
--------------------------------------------------
---19--------------394-----------------1
---26--------------781-----------------2
---83--------------842-----------------3
---83--------------450-----------------4
---83--------------453-----------------5
---83--------------456-----------------6
--104--------------621-----------------7
--104--------------622-----------------8

Here is the VBA I wrote.  I should mention this is my first time using VB so speak slowly when replying,

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public wIMG As String
Public wSEC As String
Public wRuningCount As Long

Function GetRunCount(Left_Img) As Long
    Dim sectionid As String

    If wSEC = sectionid And wIMG = Left_Img Then
       wRuningCount = wRuningCount
       wSEC = sectionid
       wIMG = Left_Img
    Else<b>
        If wSEC = sectionid And wIMG <> Left_Img Then
            wSEC = sectionid
            wIMG = Left_Img
            wRuningCount = wRuningCount + 1
        Else
            If wSEC <> sectionid Then
                wSEC = sectionid
                wIMG = Left_Img
                wRuningCount = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

    GetRunCount = wRuningCount
End Function
```

Anyone have any idea what this isn't working as I expect?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can I assume that the second Else is associated with the second If which is inside the first Else?? And that the third If is inside the second Else?? The poor indentation of your code makes it very confusing. I am making those guesses based solely on where the End Ifs are.

Comment: I submitted an edit formatting your code. The first step to debugging your code is being able to read it.

Comment: The table does not have a primary key.  I pulled data from 20 tables into a single table and omitted the primary key so I didn't have issues importing tables that had duplicate IDs.

Comment: Yea you are going to have to format the If statement flow for readability. But regardless I don't see how you are using a single global wRuningCount and then expecting to get increments per Section ID. You need something more like say a dictionary that has a key of Section ID and a value of your running count.

Comment: Sorry Mark I should have indented the code.

Comment: So Mark am I using the RunCount incorrectly?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff it's completely possible if this is run as a loop over the recordset and the "global" count is only incremented when the section if remains the same, if section I'd changes, it has to be reset to 1.

Comment: Also, whydo you declare sectionid and then immediately compare it to wSEC

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes we really need to see the code that is calling this.

Comment: That method is not going to do what you want it to at all. You need either one counter per Section ID or your calling method to be feeding them in groups of the same name as RubberDuck mentions.

Comment: Is this code equivalent (deleted the last comment, it was wrong): http://pastebin.com/B9FYCyCp

Comment: Based on your output, it appears to be going in the second If statement. Therefore I think your only problem may be defining sectionid locally instead of globally. It is always empty and therefore wSEC is always empty.

Comment: @RubberDuck I think (without seeing calling code) that you are right about how he is trying to call this function. It fits with what I think is the problem as I commented just above this.

Comment: RubberDuck I am not sure what you mean when you say you want to see the calling code.  The only other piece of this is an Access query that has the fields SectionID, Left_Img, and Running Count: GetRunCount([Left_Img])

Comment: Mark how do I define sectonid locally?

Comment: In the future put an @ in front of our names because otherwise we won't get notified that you replied to our comments. Only the main post owner gets an automatic notification. I just saw your question to me and Rubber Duck likely never saw your reply to him. I think you got your clarification in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues :

**1.** Your `sectionid` variable is local and you don't assign a value to it. Thus its always a blank string.

It should therefore fall into the latest if : `If wSEC <> sectionid Then`, however following your results, your `wRuningCount` counter is incremented each time, which means that it enters the second if : `If wSEC = sectionid And wIMG <> Left_Img Then`

The conclusion is the second issue:  
 
**2.** when you enter your function for the first time, your global `wSEC` variable is also a blank string. And it constantly stay blank because you assign a blank to it each time: `wSEC = sectionid`

It is difficult to give you a code that works without having the complete picture, ie: how do you assign a value to, or initialize your global variables  ?

Comment: When I say, "DIM sectionid As String" am I not telling it what the sectionid data is?  SectionID is a column in the data.  I thought I was telling it to look at that.

Comment: No. You simply declare a local variable of type string inside your function and this variable is thus only exposed in this function. You should declare a new input parameter to your fonction to pass the SectionID: Function GetRunCount(Left_Img as string, SectionID as string) As Long

Comment: I changed my function line to,

Comment: I changed my function line to, **Function GetRunCount(Left_Img As String, SectionID As String) As Long**.  Now I get the error, **Undefined Function 'GetRunCountGetRunCount' in expression.**  I updated my query to, **Runing count: GetRunCountGetRunCount([Left_Img as string],[SectionID as string])**  I also tried to get rid of the AS String in each and it gave me the same Undefined Function message.

Comment: Noticed that in my query I had, **Runing count: GetRunCountGetRunCount([Left_Img as string],[SectionID as string])**  Changed it to, Runing count: GetRunCount([Left_Img as string],[SectionID as string]) and now get the error, **Ambiguous name. in query expression 'GetRunCount([Left_Img],[SectionID])'.**

Comment: Issue Resolved.  Thanks for the help.  It ended up I had 2 modules both were calling the same function.  That was causing my Ambiguous Name error.  Then I ended up having to comment out the Dim SectionID As String line because the it was being declared in the function.  Works like a champ now.

Answer (score 0):

Could I describe your requirement as follow:

- if I have a new SectionID then start with Sample #1
- if I have a different Left_Img in the same section then increment the Sample by 1

So your code could look like:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private lastSection  As String
Private lastLeft_Img As String
Private RunningCount As Long

Public Sub Reset
  lastSection = vbNullString
  lastLeft_Img = vbNullString
  RunningCount = 0 
End Sub

Public Function GetRunCount(ByVal SectionID as String, ByVal Left_Img As String) As Long
  If SectionID <> lastSection Then
    RunningCount = 1
    lastLeft_Img = Left_Img
  Elseif Left_Img <> lastLeft_Img Then
    RunningCount = RunningCount + 1
    lastLeft_Img = Left_Img
  Else
    ' We have a duplicate Entry ??
  End If
  GetRunCount = RuningCount
End Function
```

Remarks:

- Don't make your Variables 'Public'
- Declare the Type of your Function Parameters
- Declare your function parameters 'ByVal' unless you explicitly want to change the value of this parameter
- name things consistently

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, sectionid is initialized as a zero length string "" and remains that way. You need to modify the function GetRunCount to include an argument of sectionid

Function GetRunCount(Left_Img, sectionid)

remove the declaration of sectionid in the function GetRunCount

and in the calling procedure, pass the sectionid along with Left_Img